# How to use rle function in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, rle

I have a `dataframe` (df) like this.

```
df <- data.frame(prox)
```

```
  year month   day Tmean

`<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>`
1  1956     1     1 13.5
2  1956     1     2 11.9
3  1956     1     3  9.71
4  1956     1     4  8.65
5  1956     1     5  4.51
6  1956     1     6  4.64
7  1956     1     7  6.66
8  1956     1     8  7.48
9  1956     1     9  5.56
10  1956     1    10  7.51
```

I want to find the maximum number of consecutive days with a  decrease in temperature.
So, I did this (with the help of @Andre Wildberg) for a single year and it works.

```
y <- rle(diff(df$Tmean) < 0) 
max(y$lengths[y$values], na.rm=TRUE) 
# [1] 6
```

But now, I want to find this, for each year (1956,1957,...). So, i' m trying to do this with `group_by`, but there is problem as `rle` is a `list`. Is it possible to do this somehow, or I have to find another way to do it?

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>%   
    summarise(x=list(rle(diff(df$Tmean) < 0)))
```

```
   year    x  
   <dbl> <list> 
1  1956 <rle>  
2  1957 <rle>
3  1958 <rle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `with` to subset the `lengths` based on the `values` and get the `max` of the `lengths` after grouping by 'year'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(x = with(rle(diff(Tmean) < 0),
        max(lengths[values], na.rm = TRUE))
)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
f1 <- function(x) {
   y <- rle(diff(x) < 0)
   max(y$lengths[y$values], na.rm = TRUE)}
aggregate(Tmean ~ year, df, f1)
```